# Потоки, многопоточность

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Сейчас есть метка [потоки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)

> Вопросы о потоках данных — абстракции, используемой для чтения или записи файлов, сокетов и т. п. в единой манере. Для потоков выполнения (threads) используйте метку [многопоточность]

и у нее есть синоним [threads](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/threads), что противоречит ее описанию.

Надо сделать [threads](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/threads) синонимом [многопоточность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c).

И для "потоков" добавить синоним [stream](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stream).

Comment: Еще для threads можно было бы добавить синоним *нити* (хотя, пока его ни разу не использовали).

Comment: @avp, да, надо. Синонимы нужны как раз для того чтобы они автозаменялись на правильные названия меток.

Comment: [Разобраться с метками касающимися потоков (threads)](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/553)

Comment: @Abyx: уточните: вы предлагаете [tag:нити] сделать основной меткой, а [tag:многопоточность] к ней синонимизировать? Или наоборот, или совсем отдельно?

Comment: @NickVolynkin многопоточность - основной (как наиболее понятный), нити - синонимом (на всякий случай).

Comment: Коллеги, а пофиксите синоним. Там каким-то макаром вместо [tag:stream] оказался [tag:thread].